# if loop to get data if present in table if not present then insert value in table and javascript to get the data on writing profile id

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I need a if loop in view file and a javascript when profile id is entered it should show all the related elements in the form and i'm doing this in codeignitor and this is the part of view file

```
                        <tr>
                            <td width='50%'>
                                <table width="50%"><tr> 
                                    <td width="50%"><strong>Profile ID </strong></td>
                                    <td width="50%"><input type="text" id="profile_id" name="profile_id" value="<?php echo $reg_personal_details->profile_id;?>"placeholder="Employee ID "/><?php echo form_error('profile_id');?><br></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr> 
                                    <td><strong>Employee Name </strong></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="profile_fname" name="profile_fname" value="<?php echo $reg_personal_details->profile_fname;?>"placeholder="Employee Name"/><?php echo form_error('profile_fname'); ?><br></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td><strong>Employee Type </strong></td>
                                    <td>
                                         <input type="text" id="profile_type" name="profile_type" value="<?php echo $reg_personal_details->profile_type;?>"placeholder="Employee Type"/><?php echo form_error('profile_type');?><br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
```

here is my table:
          profile 
                (profile_id, 
                 profile_fname, 
                 profile_lname, 
                 profile_email, 
                 profile_mobile, 
                 profile_type, 
                 profile_gender, 
                 profile_dob, 
                 profile_marital_status, 
                 profile_religion, 
                 profile_blood_group, 
                 profile_nationality, 
                 profile_iris, 
                 profile_biometric, 
                 profile_department, 
                 profile_designation, 
                 profile_project_designation, 
                 profile_image, 
                 address_1, 
                 address_2)

profile_id is a foreign key and its primary key is in other table as emp_acc_id

model for the above is :

public function reg_personal_details()

{
        $reg_personal_details = array(

```
    // i also need a condition here to read the entered profile_id all that below data must be store in that id only//

    'profile_type' => $this->input->post('profile_type'),

    'profile_gender' => $this->input->post('profile_gender'),


    'profile_dob' => $this->input->post('profile_dob'),

    'profile_marital_status' => $this->input->post('profile_marital_status'),

    'profile_religion' => $this->input->post('profile_religion'),

    'profile_blood_group' => $this->input->post('profile_blood_group'),

    'profile_nationality' => $this->input->post('profile_nationality'),

    'profile_iris' => $this->input->post('profile_iris'),

    'profile_biometric' => $this->input->post('profile_biometric'),

    'profile_department' => $this->input->post('profile_department'),

    'profile_designation' => $this->input->post('profile_designation'),
```

'profile_project_designation' => $this->input->post('profile_project_designation'),
        );

```
    $this->db->update('profile',$reg_personal_details);
```

Comment: Do a `select` on the specific data you want to check for and then check if there are rows returned. If there are, then there you go, that means it exists in the database.

Comment: Just a note about your table. you have a lot of data I would call 'private' such as blood group, biometric, nationality, marital status. I assume that to most users this info in superflouous, so I would have created a main profile table with all the things important (name, contact email, main department etc) that any user can access then have the supplemental table with access only to those that need to know it. I also suspect that some things could be tricky ie : working on a cross department project, multiple projects etc. Anyway, they're just my thoughts

Comment: Thank you and I have did it like wise only these details can be accessed only by hr and admin and yes these is lot of changes need to be done and this one is just one of the model i got a doubt, I'm working on department ... - @DaveM

Answer (score 0):

You Should write a java Script which would check if a particular element exists or not i.e if its value is not null then generate a new row tags dynamically and set its value what we get in response of the query. 
For generating a tag dynamically you can refer the following page:-

http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

> we have a function to check whether data is present or not i.e., empty()and we just need to use it in if loop like this "if (!empty($var name))" and can also use "if(empty($var name)) " so if there is no data then it doesn't show any error and if data is present in db it shows that data

```
<tr>
                                <td width='50%'>
                                    <table width="50%"><tr> 
                                            <td width="50%"><strong>Profile ID </strong></td>
                                            <td width="50%"><input type="text" id="profile_id" name="profile_id" value="<?php
                                                if (!empty($reg_personal_details)) {
                                                    echo $reg_personal_details->profile_id;
                                                } else
                                                    echo $profile_id;
                                                ?>"placeholder="Employee ID "/><?php echo form_error('profile_id'); ?><br></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php //if($reg_personal_details!=array()){  ?>
                                        <td><strong>Employee Name </strong></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="profile_fname" name="profile_fname" value="<?php
                                            if (!empty($reg_personal_details)) {
                                                echo $reg_personal_details->profile_fname;
                                            }
                                            ?>" placeholder="Employee Name"/><?php echo form_error('profile_fname'); ?><br>
                                        </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td><strong>Employee Type </strong></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="profile_type" name="profile_type" value="<?php
                                    if (!empty($reg_personal_details)) {
                                        echo $reg_personal_details->profile_type;
                                    }
                                    ?>"placeholder="Employee Type 0/1"/><?php echo form_error('profile_type'); ?><br>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
```

Comment: instead of javascript we can use if loop in php code itself